# Disable icon button in Flutter based on condition

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-animation, mobile-development

I would prefer to disable icon buttons in a screen depending on a certain condition from Firestore data.

I want to check flag's condition and disable the buttons if flag is 1.
I wrote the `onPressed` as told, but all the 'Join' buttons are disabled irrespective of the condition. Is there a logical problem here ?

Answer (score 1):

In your icon, you can use direct condition on `onPressed` function.

Whenever you want to disable the button simply provide `null` in `onPressed` otherwise your regular function Like:

```
trailing: FlatButton.icon(
  icon: Icon(Icons.add_box_rounded),
  label: Text('Join'),
  onPressed: your_condition ? 
      () async => showQueueDetailsPanel() : null,
),
```

Comment: I think the logic is right. Have you got any errors in debug console?

Comment: Can you please share how you use this function in condition?

Comment: Okay, I think I got the point. try to put `await` before that function call. `await checkUserStatus() == 0` and so on

Comment: Kindly add the return type `Future<int> checkUserStatus()` in your function definition. And then see.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IgnorePointer` and control taps disable with `ignoring` property